# Why doesn't iPhoto open automatically upon SD card insertion?

Tags: photos.app, sd-card

Inserting a SD card no longer opens iPhoto.  When I open iPhoto, it does not show the SD card in the left pane.  This program has done this without a problem until recently.  The preference under iPhoto is set to SD cards to open iPhoto.  I have also gone to Utilities/Photo Capture and ensured that iPhoto was selected in the lower left corner.  I am at wits ends because this should work automatically but is no longer doing so.  Any answers out there?

Comment: Does that card has proper folder structure or whatever? The simple fix is to format it with a camera like what orange suggests below. But I am here to give your some more information. Computers won't and shouldn't treat all SD cards as camera memory card as that will be very disturbing. My *guess* is that the system will look at the folder structure or metadata to see if that is indeed a memory card from a camera. Same theory applies to why not all SD card shows up on iPad in Photos when using Camera Connection Kit.

Comment: Let's start with this: does your Mac recognize the SD card and can it read its contents?

Answer (score 2):

A common fix for these type of issues is to reformatting the card with the camera and try inserting it again. Make sure you copy the photos from the SD Card to your computer first.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior by using Apple's Image Capture utility to set defaults for each device. (See Picture)

If this doesn't work your card is not recognized as a Photo Card

[image: screenshot of Image Capture]

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on how to do this with Image Capture? A screenshot would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Open iPhoto, and then drag the SD card symbol that is on your desktop, into a folder in iPhoto (you can create a folder and name it whatever you want). Then iPhoto will import all the contents of that SD card!